# Python: Downloading from a protected folder (.htaccess)

Tags: php, python, pyqt4

I set up on my Web server a protected area. There are two files - one txt-file and a rar-file. In the rar-file you will find a pdf-file. I have an executable program here. First, I get after a successful login to the contents of the text file. Following I grab the path (**download_path = self.url.text**). And now I try to download the file. But it does not work. Can someone help me?

```
FILE_NAME = "downloader2.py"

import os
import requests
import sys
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt, QSemaphore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialog, QProgressBar, QApplication, QMessageBox   

class Download_Thread(QThread):
    finished_thread = pyqtSignal()
    error_http = pyqtSignal()
    finished_download = pyqtSignal()
    notify_progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, location, link, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

        self.link = link

        self.location = location

        self._run_semaphore = QSemaphore(1)



    def run(self):
        try:
            self.url= requests.get(self.link, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user_name', 'user_password'))
            download_path = self.url.text
            print "URL PATH ", download_path
            file = requests.get(download_path, stream=True)
            status = self.url.status_code
            print "STATUS ", status

            if not status == 200:
                self.error_http.emit()

        except (requests.exceptions.URLRequired,
                requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
                requests.exceptions.HTTPError,
                requests.exceptions.Timeout,
                requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout,
                requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout), g:
            print 'Could not download ', g
            self.error_http.emit()
        else:
            file_size = int(requests.head(download_path).headers.get('content-length', [0]))
            print "file_size", file_size
            r = requests.head(download_path)
            print "heanders", r.headers

            print "%s Byte" %file_size
            result = 2000 / (1024*5)
            print "result", result
            chunk_size = int(result)
            print "chunk_size", chunk_size
            downloaded_bytes = 0

            with open(self.location, 'wb') as fd:
                for chunk in file.iter_content(chunk_size):
                    fd.write(chunk)
                    downloaded_bytes = fd.tell()
                    #print (float(downloaded_bytes)/file_size*100)
                    self.notify_progress.emit(float(downloaded_bytes)/file_size*100)

                    if self._run_semaphore.available() == 0:
                        self._run_semaphore.release(1)
                        break

                print "Finish"
                self.finished_download.emit()
                self.finished_thread.emit()

    def stop(self):
        print "stop"
        self._run_semaphore.acquire(1)

class MyCustomDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCustomDialog, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        #self.url = get_access_data_and_link('Sophus','danny5658')
        #print "CALLING DOWNLOAD", self.url

        self.url = 'http://xarphus.de/schutz/'

        # Create a progress bar and a button and add them to the main layout
        self.progressBarUpdate = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBarUpdate.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBarUpdate)

        pushButtonUpdate = QPushButton("Start", self)
        layout.addWidget(pushButtonUpdate)
        pushButtonCancel = QPushButton("Cancel", self)
        layout.addWidget(pushButtonCancel)

        pushButtonUpdate.clicked.connect(self.check_folder_exists)

        # Set data for download and saving in path
        self.location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('temp', 'example-app-0.3.win32.zip'))
        #self.url = 'http://sophus.bplaced.net/download/example-app-0.3.win32.zip'

        self.download_task = Download_Thread(self.location, self.url)
        self.download_task.notify_progress.connect(self.on_progress)
        self.download_task.finished_thread.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.download_task.error_http.connect(self.on_HTTPError)
        self.download_task.finished_download.connect(self.on_finish_download)

        pushButtonCancel.clicked.connect(self.on_finished)

    def on_start(self):
        self.progressBarUpdate.setRange(0, 0)
        self.download_task.start()

    def on_finish_download(self):
        msg_box = QMessageBox()

        QMessageBox.question(msg_box, ' Message ',
                                           "The file has been fully downloaded.", msg_box.Ok)

    def on_HTTPError(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, ' Error ',
                                           "The file could not be downloaded. Will they do it again?", QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.on_start()
        else:
            print "Close button pressed"
            #event.ignore()

    def on_progress(self, i):
        self.progressBarUpdate.setRange(0, 100)
        self.progressBarUpdate.setValue(i)

    def check_folder_exists(self):
        location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('temp'))
        if not os.path.exists(location):
            os.makedirs(location)
            print "Folder was created"
            self.on_start()
        else:
            print "Folder already exists"
            self.on_start()

    def on_finished(self):
        self.progressBarUpdate.setValue(0)
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.download_task.stop()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyCustomDialog()
    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run this program I get this lines on my console:

> Folder already exists
>   URL PATH  http://xarphus.de/schutz/datei.rar
>   STATUS  200
>   file_size 290
>   heanders {'content-length': '290', 'x-varnish': '150708046 150707392', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Apache', 'age': '0', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'via': '1.1 varnish', 'date': 'Wed, 22 Jul 2015 23:20:06 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1', 'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Service-Bereich"'}
>   290 Byte
>   result 0
>   chunk_size 0
>   Finish
>   stop

Comment: *Folder already exists*

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions

Comment: Hey guys, I created a test-account for you:
user_name --> test_account and
user_password --> test_user
You have to put this data in the auth=HTTPBasicAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but I have reduced my source. I hope that helps us to find the problem.

```
import requests
import shutil
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def log_in(user, pwd):
    s = requests.session()
    resp = s.get('http://xarphus.de/protect_folder/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd))
    print "Status: ", resp.status_code
    content_txt_file = resp.text
    print "Cookies: ", requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies)
    print "Content of txt file: ", content_txt_file
    print "start downloading"
    response = s.get(content_txt_file, stream=True)
    with open('test_rar.rar', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    del response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_name = 'test_account'
    user_password = 'test_user'
    log_in(user_name, user_password)
```

If I run this program that downloads the file, but the file has only 209 bytes. Its to small. The original file has round about 36 megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

So guy, although no one has helped me (for whatever reason), I found a solution. Here is the correct code:

```
def get_logged_in_session(user, pwd):

    url = 'http://xarphus.de/protect_folder'
    s = requests.session()

    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, pwd)
    resp = s.get(url=url, auth=auth)

    print "Status: ", resp.status_code
    content_txt_file = resp.text
    print "Cookies: ", s.cookies
    print "Content of txt file: ", content_txt_file
    print "init the download"
    response = s.get(url=content_txt_file, auth=auth, stream=True)
    print "start downloading"
    with open('test_rar.rar', 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    print "Closing response"
    response.close
    print "response is closed"
    print "Closing resp"
    resp.close
    print "resp is closed"
```

I have changed this line

```
response = s.get(content_txt_file, stream=True)
```

into this line

```
response = s.get(url=content_txt_file, auth=auth, stream=True)
```

Why? Well, so I can get access to the file, I need to authenticate me one more time.